# Spit sitemap for more than 50000 rows strategy in PHP / Multiple sitemap tree on index sitemap.php

Tags: php, web, sitemap

I need to make a dynamic sitemap for a huge ads website and I don't want the owner to do this job manualy and generate time to time sitemaps for all categories.
For this I was thinking of making a parent index sitemap.php (that generate sitemap XML specific code) page, page that split and contains links to other sitemaps.php (that generate sitemap XML specific code),based by categories. If I had more by 50000 rows/sitemap the script goes down on categories tree and split second subcategory.That means I could have a big number of sitemaps childs ,some of them with a single record.

On my search, oodle.com have this strategy amazom.com have too, but not dynamic .php - it is .xml.

is there a limitation of google or other search engine for how manny links to sitemaps can submit in a index sitemap file ?

Example :

```
<site-idx>
  <sub href="sitemap-1-auto.php"/>
  <sub href="sitemap-2-real-estate.php"/>
  <sub href="sitemap-3-jobs.php"/>
  ...............
  <sub href="sitemap-112-software.php"/>
</site-idx>
```

final question how can I submit index sitemap.php to all important search engine

I neead your proffesional opinion about this

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for dynamic sitemaps. Search engines don't update their search index that often, there is just not enough bandwidth. Search engines reading your sitemaps and adding the content to their engine are two very different things. You should create static xml files and update them once per month. Google isn't going add all your URLs to their index in 1 day.

You can have up to 50,000 urls or 10MB in a single sitemap file. So you can have a sitemap index file that includes links to up to 50,000 other sitemap files. I manage a site with over 7 million URLs in the sitemap files, this is how we do it and it works out well. Aside from Google taking over a month to add everything to their search index.

Comment: How do you generate those sitemaps ? Someone stay month to month to regenerate them ? Sorry I am so new in this.

Answer (score 3):

google has a max policy of 50,000 urls and to ping you can

```
function ping($sitemap_url){
@file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=" . $sitemap_url);
@file_get_contents("http://search.yahooapis.com/SiteExplorerService/V1/updateNotification?appid=YahooDemo&url=" . $sitemap_url);
@file_get_contents("http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=" . $sitemap_url);
@file_get_contents("http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=" . $sitemap_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if the mimetype is XML you can probably have .php extension. You just need the "index" file obeying the XML sitemaps protocol for xml sitemap index files. And that those individual XML sitemap files also output content that fit protocol.

You might also consider trying a tool like A1 Sitemap Generator, but if your webite is a pure DB website that is easy to code against from PHP then that is of course a good choice as well.